# Has "syntax case ignore" changed from vim 7.3 to vim 7.4?

Tags: vim, syntax, colors

I suspect that the command `syntax case ignore` has changed between the versions 7.3 and 7.4

Here is my rather small test file (`test_1.vim`):

```
syntax clear
syntax on
syntax case ignore

syntax match   garbage  "[^ \t]"
syntax match   ident    "[a-z][a-z0-9]*"
syntax keyword keyw      foo bar baz

highlight def link garbage   Error
highlight def link ident     Normal
highlight def link keyw      Function
```

I want to apply this syntax file on this file (`test_1.no-no`):

```
foo abc ABC
```

When I open the file like so

```
gvim -u NONE test_1.no-no "+source test_1.vim"
```

the three words are highlighted as expected in vim 7.3.

Yet, in vim 7.4, the word `ABC` seems to be considered *garbage* as it is highlighed with the "Error colors".

Am I missing something or is this change in appearance expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this with the Vim 7.4.000 that ships with Ubuntu 13.10, but not with a self-compiled Vim 7.4.135. Looks like a bug in the new NFA-based regular expression engine that has been fixed in the meantime.

If you cannot upgrade to a newer Vim version, you can work around this by switching back to the old engine via

```
:set regexpengine=1
```

In the future, these kind of questions and bug reports are best addressed to the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).